# What do the COUNT values in the output table of a viewshed RASTER (from multiple locations) actually indicate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, viewshed

In ArcGIS (10.1), I ran a VIEWSHED analysis using as input observer locations a POINT shapefile with 6 locations. When I open the output RASTER's attribute table, I seen that it contains a number of rows equal to the input locations, and a COUNT field.

[image]

Now, I seem having problem grasping the meaning of the latter field, and the documentation I found seems not clarify my doubt. My best guess is that those values represent the number of cells that are visible from each locations. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact table contents.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. The count field is the number of cells with the corresponding value. When I total these counts, I get `440,363`. If this doesn't match the total number of pixels that you'd calculate by multiplying `rows x columns`, then it could be that you have NoData cells which are not shown in the attribute table.

**[This page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-dataset-attribute-tables.htm)** confirms that. The documentation is for 10.3, but it's valid for previous versions of ArcGIS too.